# Is it possible to accurately calculate an irregularly shaped frustum's volume?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, 3d

I have the following water basin[image]

Now imagine this basin is filled with water to the top, is there anyway to accurately calculate the volume of water stored in it using only top and bottom areas A1 and A2? The basin is basically an irregular polygon with circular rounded edges. Furthermore the edges taper down at given slope as can be seen in the section drawing (Please disregard the red line) [image]

Ideally the volume would be a function of y or depth. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you know the bottom area, $A_2$, and the top area, $A_1$ at water height $d$.

Let's say that the bottom area is actually at a height $h$ above the unknown apex of the (inverted) pyramid, from which the frustum is created.

The area of the (inverted) base will scale as the square of the height from the apex, so

$$\frac{A_2}{h^2} = \frac{A_1}{(h + d)^2}.$$

By equating cross products and using the quadratic formula, this can be solved for $h$:

$$h = \left[\frac{A_2 + \sqrt{A_1A_2}}{A_2 - A_1}\right] d = Cd.$$

Now you can calculate the area at any water depth $y$:

$$\frac{A_2}{(Cd)^2} = \frac{A(y)}{(Cd + y)^2},$$

or

$$A(y) = \frac{A_2(Cd+y)^2}{(Cd)^2}.$$

Then, the volume of your frustum is:

$$V(y) = \frac{y}{3}\left(A_2 + \sqrt{A_2A(y)} + A(y)\right).$$

Comment: The assumption that the shape does not change with height/depth is a valid one. The problem here is A(h). How can I determine the function of the area with respect to height since this is an irregular shape? I imagine the slope must come into play (1.3 to 1) but exactly how this will impact the area is difficult for me to visualise/quantify...

Comment: I thought you said that you know $A_1$ and $A_2$. Substitute $h_1 - h_2$ with the depth of the water, and $A(h_1), A(h_2)$ with $A_1, A_2$.

Comment: I edited my answer to start with what appears to be known.  The slope is rolled into the ratio of the two areas somehow, but exactly how would need to be worked out.

Comment: Given: A2 (bottom area) and the depth of water, Uknown: A1 (top area) and Volume.